# Getting a issue while setting up the yml file for GithubActions

Tags: swift, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, building-github-actions

I am new at using Github Actions,Have written below ios.yml file and getting error like
Error: Process completed with exit code 70. on execution.

````
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and Test default scheme using any available iPhone simulator
    runs-on: macos

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set Default Scheme
        run:  sudo xcodebuild clean build test -workspace testing.xcworkspace -scheme "testing" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,OS=15.4,name=iphone 8" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO```
````

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=""` and test

Comment: also IMO, you don't require `sudo` in the start

Comment: tried by removing all this,still getting the same error. @Teju Amirthi

Comment: can you make
"platform=iOS Simulator,OS=latest,name=iphone 8"?
If it fails add a new CI/CD step, that will work:
`xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_version.app`